# Different behavior from ubuntu server and ubuntu client on windows

Tags: linux, unix, shell, shell-script

```
#!/bin/bash

# Reading

cat /home/radiare/Desktop/first.txt | while read LINE

do
echo $LINE
if [ "$LINE" == "false" ]; then
echo "Inside first loop"
break
fi
done

echo "second file read started"
cat /home/radiare/Desktop/second.txt | while read LINE

do
echo $LINE
if [ "$LINE" == "false" ]; then
echo "Inside second loop"
break
fi
done
```

In ubuntu client, I could able to execute this script and echo inside if statements are properly working. I did the same thing in ubuntu server it is not going inside the if statement. only difference is I run using sudo on the server.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you certain that `/home/radiare/Desktop/first.txt` and `/home/radiare/Desktop/second.txt` are respectively identical on both of the systems? To search for errors, add an `echo "Before if: $LINE"` before the `if` clauses. Also, instead of `cat file | while ... done`, the "right" way is `while ... done < file`.

Comment: ok, well I will try that. But you said some thing about while...done<file   can you please give some sample code.

Comment: That _was_ the sample code :-) . Instead of piping the `cat file` command into the beginning of the `while` loop, add `< file` at the end of the loop. It will not make any real difference in practice, but it is the "correct" way to do it. See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Useless_use_of_cat#Useless_use_of_cat). Don't get hung up on this point, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will try that approach aswel,for now I put echos in the above code like I modified the above code posted. The output is (false, second file read started) This means that it is reading first file properly but not going into if loop and it is not at all reading second file. Any idea why this is happening.

Comment: Since we who read the question does not now what is in the input files, we can't easily judge what the output _should_ be. Perhaps paste the input files into your question.

Comment: Both the files consist of false as data in them nothing else will be there. I tried to do the while ...done<file but the same result. It is reading first file and printing false as I echo it and then it didn't read the second file at all and I put echo in the end of the file which printed END.